# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function exif_read_data()

Tags: php

Criei um site para uma marcenaria onde o usuário faz upload das fotos dos trabalhos feitos pela marcenaria, só que quando o usuário faz upload de fotos tiradas de um determinado celular, as fotos são exibidas na horizontal no site, consegui resolver o problema verificando o exif da imagem e rotacionando a mesma quando se fizer necessário, até ai tudo bem, funciona perfeitamente no meu servidor local (XAMPP), mas quando subo os arquivos para o servidor que o meu cliente contratou para hospedar o site eu tenho o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_read_data(), a versão do PHP do meu XAMPP é 5.6 e a do servidor contratado é 5.4, não conheço outra forma de fazer essa verificação dos dados da imagem, mas preciso resolver esse problema, desde já agradeço se alguém souber de outra forma.

Answer (score 2):

Você vai ter que pedir para sua provedora de hospedagem instalar a extensão `exif`, no caso de a hospedagem suportar tal operação.

[Instalação do EXIF](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/exif.installation.php)

Caso o mesmo já esteja instalado, você também poderá habilitar no seu `php.ini` a extensão `exif`.

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Não conheço muito bem essa extensão, mas você também pode dar uma olhada nessa [pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224488/how-to-get-the-exif-php-extension-working-on-heroku)